# Loop through array with objects

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, for-loop

I have the following problem which i can't solve for 2 days now. I have an [array](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eciF3.png).

And I try to loop over it with next for..in loop

```
for (var key in products2) {
    if (products2.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
        console.log(products2[key].properties);
    }
}
```

But I can't output the value of properties object. This array is a list of products and each product has own properties.

Comment: try `jquery each` --> `$.each(product2,function(index,value){ ... })`

Comment: What is the error you are getting?

Comment: Your product is an array. Use `for` or `array.forEach` (*improvement*). Also, ideally your code should work. Can you please share the output of log?

Comment: please add the data, you are working on.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Lodash:

```
_.forEach([1, 2], function(value, index) {
    console.log(value, index);
});
```

Or you could use JavaScript:

```
var array = [1, 2]
for (var i in array) {
   alert(array[i]);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
for (var key in products2) {
    console.log(products2[key].properties);
}
```

There is no "**Key**" property in "**produts2**" array. Key variable is index of the "products2" array. Since **if** condition is not getting True, console statement is not getting executed.

Comment: Then what's the solution on this?

Comment: `key` is a variable. There is a difference between `hasOwnProperty('key')` and `hasOwnProperty(key)`

Comment: for now I have an object in my console {width: 100, height: 100, color: red}, next I should loop through products2[key].properties with for loop?

Comment: Can u share object (products2)

Answer (score 0):

first, convert it in object use JSON.parse(product2) then use your code

Answer (score 0):

It looks like an array with objects.

```
[{...}, {...}, {...}, ...]
```

For iterating the elements, you could use [`Array#forEach`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach)

```
products2.forEach(function (o) {
    Object.keys(o).forEach(function (k) {
        console.log(k, o[k]); // show key and value
    });
});
```

Comment: So if I understand correct, all OP is missing is `for..in` over `properties`. Correct?

Comment: @Rajesh, maybe, the picture of some console view ... i don't like to work with them, they could be missleading.

Comment: To be honest, in such scenarios, I prefer not to answer as it becomes difficult for readers to connect the dots and this will attract unwanted comments like this one. But this is just my POV.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
for (var i in products2) {
  for (key in products2[i]) {
    console.log(key + ":" + products2[i][key]);
  }
}
```

You have an array of objects. So first you will have to iterate through array items then you can iterate through its keys.